# Was Tom Riddle a pure-blood?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that from Pottermore there were [28 pure blood families](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood) in the 1930s. A 'Pure-Blood Directory' was subsequently published:

> *The so-called 'Sacred Twenty-Eight' comprised the families of:*
>
> *Abbott,
> Avery,
> Black,
> Bulstrode,
> Burke,
> Carrow, Crouch, Fawley, Flint, Gaunt, Greengrass
>
> Lestrange, Longbottom. Macmillan, Malfoy, Nott, Ollivander, Parkinson, Prewett, Rosier
>
> Rowle, Selwyn, Shacklebolt, Shafiq, Slughorn, Travers, Weasley and Yaxley*

**Where did Tom Riddle/Voldemort fit in this list, and was he a pure-blood?**

Comment: Any indication why the down votes? Hard to ask better questions without some direction...

Comment: you were getting downvotes because it explicitly said tom was a half blood in the books/movie, and its a major plot point as its why voldemort chose to kill harry over neville. Though it is slightly rude to downvote someone for not remembering something.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Himarm. I enjoyed reading the books and watching the movies, but don't have all the details memorized. I was reading another question, and this one popped into my head, so I asked. I agree, this isn't the warmest reception. :(

Comment: feel free to hit the chat room with questions, you can ask their first and well let you know if its a good question for the main site or not, and if its not well prob answer it for you in the chat room

Comment: The only reason you got the +3 is because of the -4. That means you net +22, not a bad deal.

Comment: This information is also readily available on Pottermore (which clearly you're familiar with, as you linked to it), and pretty much absolutely anywhere if you just google "Tom Riddle". One of the main downvote reasons is "lack of research effort" and that likely applies to why people downvoted here.

Answer (score 7):

Tom Riddle, Jr. was a half-blood, but he fits into the Gaunt family through his mother (emphasis mine):

> "So Merope," said Harry, leaning forward in his chair and staring at Dumbledore, "so **Merope was... Sir, does that mean she was... Voldemort's mother**?"
>
> "It does," said Dumbledore. "And it so happens that we also had a glimpse of Voldemort's father. I wonder whether you noticed?"
>
> "The **Muggle** Morfin attacked? The man on the horse?"
>
> "Very good indeed," said Dumbledore, beaming. "Yes, **that was Tom Riddle senior**, the handsome Muggle who used to go riding past the Gaunt cottage and for whom **Merope Gaunt** cherished a secret, burning passion."
>
> <sup><sub>*Half-Blood Prince* Chapter 10: "The House of Gaunt"</sub></sup>

Answer (score 3):

He is a half-blood from the Gaunt line. His mother was Merope Gaunt, his father, a Muggle, Tom Riddle.

Comment: His mother was a Hamster and his father smelt of elderberries.

Comment: And he blew his nose-hole in your direction.

Comment: @Zikato I would be VERY scared if Mr. V blows a nose-hole in my direction :)