# Blood Purity in Harry Potter: What is the origin of 'blood purity'

Tags: harry-potter

While talking about blood purity to Harry, Hagrid says this.

> And it's codswallop, to boot. 'Dirty blood.' Why, there isn’t a wizard alive today that’s not half-blood or less.

The question [In Harry Potter, what is the ultimate source of magicians and magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53487/in-harry-potter-what-is-the-ultimate-source-of-magicians-and-magic?s=1%7C0.4268) indicates that all Wizard families are muggle born at some point. So how did the concept of 'blood purity' arise, and what did Hagrid mean by 'Half blood or less'?

Comment: Also a fairly close dupe of [In Harry Potter, what is the ultimate source of magicians and magic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53487/in-harry-potter-what-is-the-ultimate-source-of-magicians-and-magic?s=1|0.4268)

Comment: I've edited your title, as it doesn't seem to be consistent with your actual question (which seems to be asking about blood purity and the origin of wizards). Otherwise you might get some answer talking about interbreeding with muggles. Feel free to change it back if you disagree.

Comment: @Richard I have changed to emphasis that it is the concept of blood purity that I am interested in. The origin of magic it self was just a related concept. Could you consider re opening?

Comment: With the emphasis change, you've made it into a dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105182/why-isnt-the-potter-family-in-the-pure-blood-list

Comment: Not quite. That is concerning who is called pure blood. I am trying to understand how we get from 'every one being muggle born' to 'pure blood'. and why these people think they are pure.